# Optimizar reemplazo de cadena en PHP

Tags: php, array, revisión-de-código

Yo estoy tratando un array de un tamaño considerable con algunos datos que quisiera agrupar.

Este sería un ejemplo del array:

```
[24] => Array
    (
        [0] => /03-19_solemnidad-de-san-jose-homilias/
        [1] => 53
    )

[25] => Array
    (
        [0] => /03-19_solemnidad__san-jose_homilias/
        [1] => 1
    )

[26] => Array
    (
        [0] => /03-19_solemnidad_san-jose-esposo-de-la-bienaventurada-virgen-maria_homilias/
        [1] => 970
    )

[27] => Array
    (
        [0] => /03-19_solemnidad_san-jose_homilias/
        [1] => 1622
    )

[26] => Array
    (
        [0] => /03-19_solemnidad_san-jose_homilias/
        [1] => 14
    )


[150] => Array
    (
        [0] => /19-03_solemnidad_san-jose_homilias/
        [1] => 1
    )

[151] => Array
    (
        [0] => /19-03_solemninad_san-jose_homilias/
        [1] => 1
    )

[152] => Array
    (
        [0] => /19-3_solemninad_san-jose_homilias/
        [1] => 2
    )
```

En este caso yo quiero que todos los índices `0` aquí indicados, adquieran este único valor:

`/03-19_solemnidad_san-jose-esposo-de-la-bienaventurada-virgen-maria_homilias/`

para luego aplicar otro código que ya tengo que me elimina los duplicados, sumando el valor del índice `1` al valor único que quedará.

Para igualar todos los valores del índice `0` lo estoy haciendo uno por uno:

```
$row[0]=str_replace('/03-19_solemnidad-de-san-jose-homilias/', '/03-19_solemnidad_san-jose-esposo-de-la-bienaventurada-virgen-maria_homilias/', $row[0]);

$row[0]=str_replace('/03-19_solemnidad__san-jose_homilias/', '/03-19_solemnidad_san-jose-esposo-de-la-bienaventurada-virgen-maria_homilias/', $row[0]);

...
```

Lo que quiero saber es si hay alguna forma de optimizar el reemplazo. Por ejemplo, creando un array o algo así, en el que se encuentre el valor definitivo y los valores a buscar/reemplazar, en lugar de hacerlo uno por uno.

Comment: Hola! Para la parte en que igualas el valor en 0, ¿no recorres el array original en un ciclo?

Comment: @quinqui sí, yo recorro el array original y hago la sustitución para que todos me queden igual. Y luego recorro el array de nuevo y elimino los duplicados. Lo que quiero es que en ese primer recorrido no tener que hacer los reemplazos uno por uno, sino tener como un array por cada caso, en ese array habría los posibles valores a encontrar y un valor con el que reemplazar. Esa es la idea que tengo, no sé si sea lo mejor ni tampoco cómo lograrlo.

Comment: Uy, sabes, me pillas XD Es que no le hallo el problema, me gustaría ayudarte, podría ser por chat? (no sé cómo abrir un chat desde aquí...)

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que puedo ver en tu pregunta tienes un arreglo de arreglos, entonces es suficiente con recorrer el arreglo completo para después en cada uno de los arreglos internos remplazar el valor en su campo `0` por el valor por default que tu quieres asignar.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
$arreglo = [
   ["/03-19_solemnidad_san-jose-esposo-de-la-bienaventurada-virgen-maria_homilias/",970],
   ["/03-19_solemnidad_san-jose_homilias/",1622],
   ["/03-19_solemnidad_san-jose_homilias/12",1500],
   ["/03-19_solemnidad_san-jose_homilias/aaawasd",1622]
];

foreach($arreglo as $dato){
   $dato[0] = "/03-19_solemnidad_san-jose-esposo-de-la-bienaventurada-virgen-maria_homilias/";
} 
?>
```